# Java Semaphore, acquire() and release()

Tags: java, semaphore

I am a beginner to java and I was experiment with Semaphore.
I tried to write a code that has writers and reader, I only tried to use acquire() and release():

> 1) If a writer is writing, then at the same time no other writer can write and no reader can read.
>   2) Multiple readers can read at the same time, but if there is at least one active reader then writers can't write anything.

So, in summary, there can be either
- one reader and no writer
- multiple readers and no writer
- one writer and no reader

I tried to write the code below, I know it is probably horribly bad but I really struggle to understand the concept and the code is not working and I don't know how to fix it.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Main 
{


    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ReadWriteLock RW = new ReadWriteLock();

        executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));
        executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));
        executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));
        executorService.execute(new Writer(RW));

        executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
        executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
        executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));
        executorService.execute(new Reader(RW));                
    }
}


class ReadWriteLock
{


    private int reader = 0;
    private Semaphore write = new Semaphore(1);

    public void readLock()  
    {           
        if (write.availablePermits() == 1)
        {
            reader++;
        }
    }

    public void writeLock() 
    {       
        if (write.availablePermits() == 1)
        {
            try 
            {
                write.acquire();
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();;
            }
        }

    }

    public void readUnLock() 
    {
         if (reader > 0)
            reader--;
    }

    public void writeUnLock() 
    {

        if (write.availablePermits() == 0)
        {
            write.release();
        }

    }

}




class Writer implements Runnable
{
   private ReadWriteLock RW_lock;


    public Writer(ReadWriteLock rw) {
        RW_lock = rw;
   }

    public void run() {
      while (true){
          RW_lock.writeLock();

          RW_lock.writeUnLock();

      }
   }


}



class Reader implements Runnable
{
   private ReadWriteLock RW_lock;


   public Reader(ReadWriteLock rw) {
        RW_lock = rw;
   }
    public void run() {
      while (true){               
          RW_lock.readLock();


          RW_lock.readUnLock();

      }
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following solution to the reader writer problem using semaphores. It takes care of all the mentioned conditions and uses the `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` package to implement semaphores.
http://www2.hawaii.edu/~walbritt/ics240/synchronization/ReaderWriterSolution.java

You have to define locks on the reader and writer. Following is an interface for all the reader lock.

```java
interface RWLock{
       public abstract void acquireReadLock(int readerNum);
       public abstract void acquireWriteLock(int writerNum);
       public abstract void releaseReadLock(int readerNum);
       public abstract void releaseWriteLock(int writerNum);
   }
```

`Database.java` holds the definition of all the read and write function:

```java
class Database implements RWLock{
      private int readerCount;  // the number of active readers
      private Semaphore mutex;  // controls access to readerCount
      private Semaphore db;     // controls access to the database

       public Database() {
         readerCount = 0;
         mutex = new Semaphore(1);
         db = new Semaphore(1);
      }

       public void acquireReadLock(int readerNum) {
         try{
         //mutual exclusion for readerCount 
            mutex.acquire();
         }
             catch (InterruptedException e) {}

         ++readerCount;

      // if I am the first reader tell all others
      // that the database is being read
         if (readerCount == 1){
            try{
               db.acquire();
            }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
         }

         System.out.println("Reader " + readerNum + " is reading. Reader count = " + readerCount);
         //mutual exclusion for readerCount
         mutex.release();
      }

       public void releaseReadLock(int readerNum) {
         try{
         //mutual exclusion for readerCount
            mutex.acquire();
         }
             catch (InterruptedException e) {}

         --readerCount;

      // if I am the last reader tell all others
      // that the database is no longer being read
         if (readerCount == 0){
            db.release();
         }

         System.out.println("Reader " + readerNum + " is done reading. Reader count = " + readerCount);

      //mutual exclusion for readerCount
         mutex.release();
      }

       public void acquireWriteLock(int writerNum) {
         try{
            db.acquire();
         }
             catch (InterruptedException e) {}
         System.out.println("Writer " + writerNum + " is writing.");
      }

       public void releaseWriteLock(int writerNum) {
         System.out.println("Writer " + writerNum + " is done writing.");
         db.release();
      }


   }
```

Now you will need to implement the reader and writer respectively. By acquiring the locks and following the mentioned conditions:

- one reader and no writer
- multiple readers and no writer
- one writer and no reader

```java
class Reader implements Runnable
   {

      private RWLock database;
      private int readerNum;

       public Reader(int readerNum, RWLock database) {
         this.readerNum = readerNum;
         this.database = database;
      }

       public void run() {
         while (true) {
            SleepUtilities.nap();

            System.out.println("reader " + readerNum + " wants to read.");
            database.acquireReadLock(readerNum);

         // you have access to read from the database
         // let's read for awhile .....
            SleepUtilities.nap();

            database.releaseReadLock(readerNum);
         }
      }
   ;
   }

   class Writer implements Runnable
   {
      private RWLock database;
      private int writerNum;

       public Writer(int w, RWLock d) {
         writerNum = w;
         database = d;
      }

       public void run() {
         while (true){
            SleepUtilities.nap();

            System.out.println("writer " + writerNum + " wants to write.");
            database.acquireWriteLock(writerNum);

         // you have access to write to the database
         // write for awhile ...
            SleepUtilities.nap();

            database.releaseWriteLock(writerNum);
         }
      }


   }
```

Finally you need a running class to test the solution

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

    public class ReaderWriterSolution{
      public static final int NUM_OF_READERS = 3;
      public static final int NUM_OF_WRITERS = 2;

       public static void main(String args[]){
         RWLock database = new Database();

         Thread[] readerArray = new Thread[NUM_OF_READERS];
         Thread[] writerArray = new Thread[NUM_OF_WRITERS];

         for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_READERS; i++) {
            readerArray[i] = new Thread(new Reader(i, database));
            readerArray[i].start();
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_WRITERS; i++) {
            writerArray[i] = new Thread(new Writer(i, database));
            writerArray[i].start();
         }
      }
   }
```

All the classes have been included in the solution.
Hope it helps!